# How to restore a missing prepackaged driver

Tags: windows-8

When uninstalling a usb peripheral, I deleted the driver that comes prepacked in Windows. The OEM's website proudly says that the driver comes with Windows and doesn't need to be installed.

How can I get the driver back? I suspect I can use a Windows install dvd but I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: Maybe a System Restore?